# Вывод определенного заголовка в зависимости от рубрики wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт с двумя категориями: Дом и Квартиры. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в записи (single.php) выводился заголовок Похожие дома или Похожие квартиры в зависимости от рубрики, к которой принадлежит запись.
Например, если запись из рубрики Дома, то выводить внизу контента Похожие дома. А если запись из рубрики Квартиры, то выводить Похожие квартиры.

Посоветовали такой код, но он не во всех записях срабатывает. Где работает отлично, где-то ничего не вываодит. Вывожду внутри цикла.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$cat_slug = $categories[0]->slug;
if ( $cat_slug === 'houses') {
  echo 'Похожие дома';
} elseif ($cat_slug === 'flats') {
  echo 'Похожие квартиры';
}
```

Comment: У вас только 2 категории , Дома и Квартиры, или еще какие-то есть?

Comment: Только две родительские категории Дома и Квартиры. Каждая родительская содержит множество дочерних категорий. Каждая запись принадлежит одной родительской и дочерней категории.

Comment: Вероятно, в `$categories[0]` у вас иногда попадает не родительская, а дочерняя категория. В таком случае вам необходимо проверять дополнительно `$categories[1]`